# Transpose array to rows in Netezza

Tags: sql, arrays, transpose, netezza

I am attempting to use the following SQL script, adapted from [here](http://nz2nz.blogspot.ca/2016/09/netezza-transpose-delimited-string-into.html) in Solution 1, to transpose arrays to separate rows.

When I run it, it only retrieves the first element of the array.  I would like all elements of the array to show.  Yesterday, I remember modifying some part of this script and it appeared to run correctly.  However I didn't save the script!

```html
SELECT F.ROWID 
        , C.CNT
        , SQLEXT..get_value_varchar(ARR,CAST(DECODE(SIGN(LEN-c.CNT),1,c.CNT,null) AS INT) ) AS ELEMENT_NM  
FROM    (SELECT   ROWID
                , SQLEXT..ARRAY_SPLIT(FINELINE_NM,';')      AS ARR
                , SQLEXT..ARRAY_COUNT(SQLEXT..ARRAY_SPLIT(FINELINE_NM,';')) AS LEN
        FROM    DATABASE.DEV_LDG_REPORT         
        )                                                   AS F
CROSS JOIN (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1)          AS CNT
            FROM    (SELECT *
                        FROM DATABASE.DEV_LDG_REPORT
                        LIMIT 100)                          AS V
            )                                               AS C
WHERE DECODE(SIGN(LEN-C.CNT),1, C.CNT, NULL) IS NOT NULL
;
```

Essentially, I would like this:

```
ID        FINELINE_NM
1         123;124;125
2         123;124;125;126
```

To look like this:

```
ID        FINELINE_NM
1         123
1         124
1         125
2         123
2         124
2         125
2         126
```

Are there any modifications in the above script which you could see it allowing all elements to be returned in the result?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As a reminder, please refrain from just linking to external sources containing substantive relevant details, as they may change or be removed at a later time. It's okay to include a link, but consider including anything relevant to your question into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand:

- The table `C` in the `CROSS JOIN` is just to generate a list of numbers to index into the array positions. If there are fewer records in `DATABASE.DEV_LDG_REPORT` than there are entries in an array, you won't reach the end
- also, `DECODE(SIGN(LEN-c.CNT),1,c.CNT,null)` returns null when `LEN` = `c.CNT` (i.e. the `SIGN` is 0), so this will miss the last entry in the array. Better to use `LEN+1-c.CNT` inside the `SIGN` function